# How to perform bitwise OR and NOT scalar operations in AWS Redshift?

Tags: bit-manipulation, amazon-redshift

AWS Redshift has bitwise &, <<, >> scalar operatos for AND, SHIFT LEFT, and SHIFT RIGHT but what about the bitwise OR and NOT?

Look at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_OPERATOR_SYMBOLS.html

Is there exist any way to perform it?

Answer (score 0):

For bitwise OR you can use

> (column_name) | (column_name)

For bitwise NOT you can use

> ~(column_name)

If I’ve made a bad assumption please comment and I’ll refocus my answer.

Comment: BIT_OR() is not scalar, it is only applies for AGGREGATIONS however ~ seems do the NOT scalar job, is curious that not be mentioned in the link I provided

Comment: @JairoAndresVelascoRomero - Sorry did not read your question properly. Edited my answer. Redshift Documentation is not very accurate